# How to accept only the next word in github copilot suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

I would like to be able to accept only the next word of a github Copilot suggestion, instead of the full suggestion. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut is now "Cmd/Ctrl + Right Arrow".

For custom keybindings, paste something like the following into the `keybindings.json` file (which you can find through the omnibox):

```json
{
  "key": "shift+ctrl+right"    
  "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.acceptNextWord",
  "when": "inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Comment: Note: The vim Extensions `extension.vim_cmd+right` shortcut has higher precedence seemingly, so I had to remove that shortcut for the partial accept to work.

Comment: I can't get this to work, it moves to the next desktop on mac. Any way to map to something else? Using nvim and github/copilot.vim

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in Visual Studio 22? The difference in available keybindings is painful.

Answer (score 8):

This option exists in VSCode keyboard preferences, but is not enabled by default (though a default keybinding might be [coming soon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/171251)). To enable a shortcut to accept only the next word, in VS Code go to File -> Preferences -> KeyboardShortcuts -> type "acceptNextWord" -> click "+" -> enter your desired keyboard shortcut.

I set acceptNextWord to be `alt + RightArrow` to be analogous to Copilot's `alt + ]` and `alt + [` for next suggestion and previous suggestion.

Comment: The default keybinding has arrived, see @Amiratak88 answer.

Comment: I wish this existed for Visual Studio too as it's a great feature.