# How to accept only the next word in PyCharm GitHub copilot suggestion

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, github-copilot

I would like to be able to accept only the next word of a github Copilot suggestion instead of the full suggestion. This is possible with VS Code as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114315/how-to-accept-only-the-next-word-in-github-copilot-suggestion#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20a%20shortcut%20to,enter%20your%20desired%20keyboard%20shortcut.).
Is there a way to do this in PyCharm too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been added with a recent update for the GitHub Copilot extension. One may now hit `Ctrl + Right` to accept the next word only, and in a multiline suggestion also `Ctrl + Alt + Right` to accept the next line only.