# How to accept only the next word with github copilot suggestion in Rstudio?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

GitHub copilot is generally offering long sentences, I wish to accept word by word, for example using `ctrl + right` arrow, instead of the full suggestion. Is there a way to do this in Rstudio?

This solution already exists for: [VS-code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75114315/14361772) and [PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76269633/14361772).

Looked into the [Rstudio documentation](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/tools/copilot.html) and did not find it.

Comment: Update: solution found at [posit forum](https://forum.posit.co/t/github-copilot-partial-inline-completion-acceptance-word-by-word/181499), `Tools > Modify Keyboard Shortcuts... > Co-pilot: Accept Next Word`.

Comment: See [Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13522)